# jquery not working online (but it works offline)

Tags: jquery

I have a simple online form with jQuery calling a JSON file containing a list of countries. The page populate a select list and works fine offline but not online. You can see the HTML source code at

http://governapps.com/qualys/index.cfm

The jQuery code is at the bottom.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks,

David

Comment: What do you mean by "offline but not online"? You mean on a local server?

Comment: Just a side FYI, you can go ahead and include the jQuery inside the `<head>` of the page, and run your startup scripts inside `$(function(){ })`.  It ensures nothing runs before the entire DOM is loaded, so there's no need to put things at the bottom of the page anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `iso-3166-countries.en.json` url is wrong or it can't be served correctly (mime types, permissions, etc).

If the url is right, an easy way would be to rename it to `iso-3166-countries.en.cfm`, and of course change the `$.getScript` to reflect it to.

Hope this helps

Comment: woohoo!!! That was it! I renamed .json to .txt and updated my jquery code correspondingly and it worked. I guess the server couldn't handle the .json file extension. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like iso-3166-countries.en.json is not being served correctly in IIS (maybe .json MIME is not defined in your IIS) or the relative path to it is not correct; Because it just throws error 404 (resource not exists error).

Comment: I also recommend using Fiddler for web debugging (freeware). At lease you would see the server errors when they happen. – Parsa 21 mins ago